# Python String encoding - file name

Tags: python, linux, encoding, amazon-s3

str(file.key) = '1011/101011/file_name'

```
newFileName = str(file.key)
```

But, when I run the code i get:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   x-y: ordinal not in range(128)

I need to do some parsing on the file name and then download it from s3 server.
How do I get just 'file_name'?

Comment: Please post a full and minimal test case.

Comment: What it says: Post the least amount of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: We'd love to see what file.key actually is (the type, how it came to be). Also, you'r not telling us what you want to do with `newFileName`, which can be very relevant for an proposed alternative. If possible, provide something an answerer could run to see the problem and investigate.

Comment: Create a script that is as short as possible, but will still produce this error. Put this script in this question, as well as the full results of running it (not just one line of the traceback). There are two good reasons for this: (1) it will ensure that you post enough information for us to help you; and (2) often going through this exercise will make it obvious to you where the error lies.

Additionally, you have an amazon-s3 tag on this question, but as written, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with Amazon S3. This is confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the missed information. but @Koert has answered my question. The problem was that I'm tried to import code from python 2.7 on mac os to linux server with python 2.5.2 and there are diffreneces. I wanted to lok for terms in newFileName. file.key is a s3 key (from a bucket). But as I said Koert solved my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted far to little context to give a decent answer, but I'll try anyway.

The filename you are trying to create seems to contain non-ascii characters, which cannot be automatically be converted into a standard str in python 2.x.

If you replace `str` with `unicode` you can avoid the need for conversion alltogether. If some other part of your code requires you to use an str, you could try to encode it like this: `newFileName = unicode(file.key).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`. Note that unconvertable characters will be omitted in my example.